# is LLDP through routed openvpn possible?

Tags: linux, openvpn, lldp

I would like to have LLDP traffic forwarded between client & server. Is it possible to achieve this using routed openVPN configuration?

P.S.: LLDP works with bridged openVPN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LLDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Discovery_Protocol) is a layer 2 protocol. Therefore it cannot work over a routed connection.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible with [VxLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Extensible_LAN)

Extract : 
Virtual Extensible LAN (VXLAN) is a network virtualization technology that attempts to ameliorate the scalability problems associated with large cloud computing deployments. It uses a VLAN-like encapsulation technique to encapsulate MAC-based OSI layer 2 Ethernet frames within layer 4 UDP packets, using 4789 as the default IANA-assigned destination UDP port number

But you need equipment at each end that are VxLAN capable

Comment: It would also require OpenVPN to run on a separate node from the one you want to run LLDP on, so that you can insert the VxLAN capable equipment between the two. (In fact you could probably contrive a setup with a bridge interface, a VxLAN driver and OpenVPN stacked on top of each other on a single machine, but I would not consider that a suitable setup for a business environment.)